# How to publish my own library to TFS?

Tags: android, gradle, tfs, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I create my own library looking this sample below .

https://medium.com/@ome450901/publish-an-android-library-by-jitpack-a0342684cbd0

But I want to publish it to tfs server . But I dont know it is possible or how can I make it . I search it at google but I cannot find anything .

thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Create a feed in tfs server first, then publish the library to the feed, just follow Vampire's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/overview and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/get-started-maven, you need at least TFS 2018 for Maven package repository being available and additionally you have to have Package Management installed and licensed (or in trial mode) and additionally the TFS admin has to enable "Maven for Package Management" in the "Preview Features" section of the settings.

If all this is given, you can create a feed for Maven package management and then you can use the [`maven`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) or [`maven-publish`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) Gradle plugin to publish to that TFS feed you created. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/get-started-maven should give you an indication on what settings you need to publish to configure the respective Gradle plugin.

As I don't have TFS available, I cannot give you a concrete example.