# Push Android artifact to Azure DevOps Feed

Tags: android, azure-devops, package-managers

I am building my Android projects with Azure pipelines, but I'm still copy pasting aar files from libraries to apps. How do I publish my libs in a private package manager, so I can use them in my apps?

With c# / nuget I got this working easily. Feeds seem to support Maven/Gradle, but I don't see how I can push my libs into a feed (builds are successfull). What's the "nuget push" equivalent?

I find alot about how to sign/publish apps, and documentation on how to do it with Xamarin, which uses ... nuget. Do I need to write Grade / Maven stuff myself, eventhough pipeline tasks are all over the place and there's a *DevOps for Mobile* youtube series (Xamarin)?

Please point me in the direction of some not outdated documentation and/or how I can learn what to put in my yaml files.

Comment: Here is a [blog](https://softwarehut.com/blog/tech/case-study-library-releases-and-how-to-do-them) about the Android library, with the Gradle build system. You can view to see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's a possibility. But the goal is not to publish from my local machine. I want a pipeline configured by a yaml file to do stuff, so I can use all of what Azure has to offer regarding CI/CD.

Comment: Not get your latest information, are the workarounds below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I read through them, but at this point I already dropped too many resources on this topic. I decided to go back to copy & pasting aar files, since that is more efficient. I could have manually built years worth of projects in the time it takes me to get this running.

Answer (score 0):

> Push Android artifact to Azure DevOps Feed

You could use [maven](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) new [maven-publish plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) with following gradle build config to publish Android artifact to Azure DevOps Feed:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier "sources"
}

publishing {
    publications {
        bar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.foo'
            artifactId 'bar'
            version '0.1'
            artifact(sourceJar)
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/bar-release.aar")
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "$buildDir/repo"
        }
    }
}
```

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874498/publish-an-android-library-to-maven-with-aar-and-source-jar) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869463/how-to-publish-my-own-library-to-tfs) for some details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> but I'm still copy pasting aar files from libraries to apps

In this case, if you want to publish a set of related files from a pipeline as a single package, you can use [Universal Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops) hosted in Azure Artifacts feeds.

Universal Packages are created from a directory of files. By default, the Universal Packages task will publish all files in `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. To prepare your Universal Package for publishing, either configure preceding tasks to place output files in that directory, or use the [Copy Files utility task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops) to assemble the files that you want to publish.

To publish a Universal Package to your feed, add the following snippet to your azure-pipelines.yml file.

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: Universal Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    vstsFeedPublish: '<Feed name>'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: '<Package name>'
    packagePublishDescription: '<Package description>'
```

You can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for details.